# how to run a program with root privilege in a remote linux host

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo

I want to run a program on many remote hosts
these program may run serveral hours and it needs root privilege 
I have uploaded the program to those remote hosts 
I can only ssh into those machines with my username
but with my username I can `sudo` without password

now I want to write a automation script to run them  on those hosts

basically I need something like:

```
for remote_host in host_list:
     run the program on remote_host
```

and then the script quits.
I tried

```
ssh -t usr@remote_host "sudo /home/usr/program"
```

but this will block my shell until the program quits
so I tried

```
ssh -t usr@remote_host "sudo /home/usr/program" &
```

it does'nt work, I use `ps -ef` to check and find no process

I also tried python `paramiko`, but failed
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085502/run-remote-program-with-root-priviledge-using-paramiko-ssh-channel

I also want to log all output from running the program

can anyone give some solutions? 
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
ssh -t usr@remote_host 'sudo nohup bash -c "/home/user/program > /dev/null 2>&1 &"'
```

The `nohup` should allow your shell to exit without killing the program that you are running. Drop the `-t` option if you don't want the `nohup.out` file to be created.

Comment: Why do you need the “`bash -c`”?  Wouldn’t “`sudo nohup /home/user/program …`” be just as good?

Comment: @Scott: Good question. Seem to need it in order to keep the ``&`` from being associated with the ``nohup``.

Comment: If the program intended to run needs tty, e.g., tcpdump, the ``-t`` option is necessary, even if you don't want the ``nohup.out`` file to be created.